# calculate roll_rank using prev value for each row

Tags: kdb

I have a table where we need to set and sum roll_rank except from roll_rank 0,1,2
we dont need to touch the rows where roll_rank in 0,1,2
we want to calculate sums of roll_rank by date where not roll_rank in 0,1,2.

example table:

```
tmp:([]date:`date$();name:`symbol$();roll_rank:`int$())
`tmp insert (2010.01.01;`sym1;1);
`tmp insert (2010.01.01;`sym2;2);
`tmp insert (2010.01.01;`sym3;0Ni);
`tmp insert (2010.01.01;`sym4;0Ni);
`tmp insert (2010.01.02;`sym1;0);
`tmp insert (2010.01.02;`sym2;1);
`tmp insert (2010.01.02;`sym3;2);
`tmp insert (2010.01.02;`sym4;0Ni);
`tmp insert (2010.01.02;`sym5;0Ni);
`tmp insert (2010.01.02;`sym6;0Ni);
`tmp insert (2010.01.03;`sym1;1);
`tmp insert (2010.01.03;`sym2;0Ni);
`tmp insert (2010.01.03;`sym3;0Ni);
`tmp insert (2010.01.03;`sym4;0Ni);
```

[image]

Expected output is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might also achieve your desired result:

```
update sums 1^deltas roll_rank by date from tmp
```

Comment: Thank you Terry, I'm impressed with your solution. Its super fast for for big dataset.
As compared to Cathal  solution, your solution is 5x faster as I have big dataset to apply on. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

One method using a [vector conditional](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/vector-conditional/) and [over](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/over/):

```
q){update{?[null x;1+prev x;x]}roll_rank from x}/[tmp]
date       name roll_rank
-------------------------
2010.01.01 sym1 1
2010.01.01 sym2 2
2010.01.01 sym3 3
2010.01.01 sym4 4
2010.01.02 sym1 0
2010.01.02 sym2 1
2010.01.02 sym3 2
2010.01.02 sym4 3
2010.01.02 sym5 4
2010.01.02 sym6 5
2010.01.03 sym1 1
2010.01.03 sym2 2
2010.01.03 sym3 3
2010.01.03 sym4 4
```

Comment: Thank you Cathal for your quick response, your solution is working.